# Will temp variable in always_comb create latch

Tags: verilog, hdl, system-verilog

I have following code snippet where a temp variable is used to count number of 1s in an array:

```
   // count the number 1s in array 
   logic [5:0] count_v; //temp
   always_comb begin
      count_v = arr[0];
      if (valid) begin
         for (int i=1; i<=31; i++) begin
            count_v = arr[i] + count_v;
         end
      end
      final_count = count_v;
   end
```

Will this logic create a latch for count_v ? Is synthesis tool smart enough to properly synthesize this logic? I am struggling to find any coding recommendation for these kind of scenarios.

Another example:

```
logic temp; // temp variable
always_comb begin
   temp = 0;
   for (int i=0; i<64; i++) begin
      if (i>=start && i<start+3) begin
         out_data[temp*8 +: 8] = in_data[i*8 +: 8];
         temp = temp + 1'b1;
      end
   end
end
```

Above example is related to bit slicing where the input is 64Bytes and the output is less than 64Bytes (3Bytes for example, starting from byte# `start`). I know that there are better ways to code this but I still want to know how the synthesis tool will interpret the design here.

Comment: I don't know. I'm guessing the second one would be "no", the first case "maybe". Synthesize it yourself and let us know. It should be easy to check.

Comment: I don't know enough SystemVerilog to answer this confidently, but think about what `count_v` represents. You declare it as a single 6-bit signal. But actually in each iteration of the `for` loop, it represents the output of a different adder. So there are actually 31 different signals that are called `count_v` in different iterations of the for loop.

Comment: Also, the hardware described by the first code will be quite slow because any change in `arr[1]` has to propagate through 31 adders before `final_count` will get its correct resulting value.

Answer (score 1):

If within the `always_comb` block your assignment comes before any read access, there is no latch. You should get an error if there is any possible flow through the block if there was a read before any write to a local variable.